# How to version control 2 different files in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

How can I use Visual Studio 2019 and the Azure-GIT option in it to version control 2 different python files that I use in the VS solution ?
I create new project ( python type ) and VS automatically creates a blank .py file.

When the solution only has that 1 python file, I can add code, make changes, put that into source control and I see it's details in the team explorer view pane. That works OK. I can commit changes, create new branches, view the history, etc

But ... If I then close the file and create a new additional python file and add that to the solution, make changes, save it ,etc

I cannot manage to put that 2nd file under source control. The team explorer incorrectly continues to display the details of only the first file and in fact it still displays the branch structure, history , etc of the 1st file NOT the 2nd file I now have open and I am making changes to.

How can I get the team explorer / Azure / GIT functions to switch over and work on the additional new 2nd python file ?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: git branches are not for a single file but for the repo/project.

Comment: Thank you reminding me of this ( very basic ) fact, which answers my question.  My question should be closed - thanks.